# Tengo un error con array_merge

Tags: php, array

En realidad no es un error, es una advertencia que me gustaría eliminar.

Les paso el código y el error a ver si alguien sabe cómo se soluciona.

```php
function brc_hidden_meta_boxes( $hidden ) {
    $hidden = array_merge( $hidden, array( 'slugdiv' ) );

    return $hidden;
}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la advertencia?

Comment: Puedes dejar en claro que necesitas????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás haciendo un `array_merge()` cuando en realidad tu intención es agregar un dato más a tu arreglo, mientras que `array_merge()` combina dos arreglos.

PHP: array_merge

> Combina los elementos de uno o más arrays juntándolos de modo que los valores de uno se anexan al final del anterior. Retorna el array resultante.

Haciendo caso a la documentación, `array_merge()` combina **los** (plural) valores de uno o más arrays. Si el OP quiere agregar un solo dato en específico, ¿por qué ocupar algo que en ESE caso no es necesario?

Para tu caso debería ser :

```
function brc_hidden_meta_boxes( $hidden ) {
    $hidden[] = 'slugdiv';

    return $hidden;
}
```

Comment: y si `$hidden` es un array?

Comment: asumo que `$hidden` es un arreglo.. lo propongo es que en vez de hacer merge de 1 solo valor en un arreglo, agrege el valor en bruto como ultimo elemento de `hidden` @aldanux

Comment: ya pero... las dos maneras son validas...y no debe de imprimir ninguna advertencia... y es eso lo que quiere saber/eliminar el OP

Comment: Ninguna de las dos genera advertencias, sin embargo voy a eliminar mi pregunta ya que el OP no especifica claro lo que necesita! @aldanux

Comment: Gracias funciono perfecto como dice sioesi

Comment: @SantiagoD'Antuoni  me alegro que haya servido! Para otros casos recuerda plantear bien tu pregunta, dejar el codigo y explicar lo que haz intentado hacer y los errores que tienes. Asi sera mas facil aun ayudarte! Saludos